# Luracast restler 3 returns nothing

Tags: restler

I've messed something up on my installation of restler.  Down in a subfolder of my website where I want the REST api I put the vendor directory that comes with restler (got rid of everything else), and then I created an index.php file at that same level:

```php
<?php
require_once 'vendor/restler.php';
use Luracast\Restler\Restler;

$r = new Restler();
$r->addAPIClass('Test');
$r->handle();
?>
```

The .htaccess file at this level is just the one from the Restler documentation without change.  Then I created a simple Test.php file that just returns a JSON array:

```php
<?php
class Test {
    function index() {
        return [1, 2, 3];
    }
}
?>
```

Querying that URL now returns nada:

```
curl -i https://.../dts/restler/Test
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Sun, 20 Jul 2014 18:20:40 GMT
Server: Apache/2.2.26 (Unix) DAV/2 PHP/5.4.24 mod_ssl/2.2.26 OpenSSL/0.9.8y
X-Powered-By: PHP/5.4.24
MS-Author-Via: DAV
Vary: User-Agent
Content-Length: 0
Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
```

Notice how the "X-Powered-By" is just plain PHP?  If I give a different name than test, I actually get an error from Restler:

```
curl -i https://.../dts/restler/Invalid
HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found
Date: Sun, 20 Jul 2014 18:22:18 GMT
Server: Apache/2.2.26 (Unix) DAV/2 PHP/5.4.24 mod_ssl/2.2.26 OpenSSL/0.9.8y
X-Powered-By: Luracast Restler v3.0.0rc5
Vary: Accept,User-Agent
Cache-Control: no-cache, must-revalidate
Expires: 0
Content-Language: en
MS-Author-Via: DAV
Content-Length: 360
Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8

{
    "error": {
        "code": 404,
        "message": "Not Found"
    },
    "debug": {
        "source": "Routes.php:436 at route stage",
        "stages": {
            "success": [
                "get"
            ],
            "failure": [
                "route",
                "negotiate",
                "message"
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

So the root of my site is .../dts, but I want to have all my restful API stuff in the restler subdirectory to keep things clean.

Comment: can you saw your .htaccess

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, I just figured this out.  I had to move the .htaccess to the root of the website and then changed the RewriteRule to have rester/index.php instead of just index.php